# CSS style color uneffective on star character (&#9733;) on Samsung with Android 4.4 KitKat

Tags: android, html, css, android-4.4-kitkat, samsung-mobile

On my dedicated mobile website, I use the html star character ★ `&#9733;` and I apply CSS on it, especially `color`.

```
<span class="orange">&#9733; &#9733; &#9733;</span>
<span class="grey">&#9733; &#9733;</span>

.orange {
    color: orange:
}

.grey {
    color: grey;
}
```

Everything works well on most browsers and os, like this:

[image]

But on Samsung devices with **Android 4.4 kitkat (Galaxy S4, S5...)**, the stars are natively styled by touchwiz (I suppose) and the color property has no effect anymore on stock browser and Chrome, but not Firefox !
And it works well on other kitkat **(LG G2, Nexus 7) or Samsung with Jelly Bean**.

[image]

I tried webkit specific style like *`-webkit-text-fill-color`, with no effect*.

I looked for all webkit style, but nothing seems to correspond except `-webkit-text-fill-color`.

I know others way to make stars like images, custom font-face or even CSS shapes, but simpler would be better.

So, have you ever seen that and found the magic style that works ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found what the problem was. It’s inside the fonts of the system, in this file exactly :

```
/system/fonts/NotoColorEmoji.ttf
```

By changing this font (Samsung emoji) with another with native Android emoji, the stars appear normally.
I found the method here : [XDA - [MOD] Emoji iOS / Google on Samsung S4 Kit Kat](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2618523).

So it’s not possible to tweak Samsung stars directly.

Since I have multiple colors and sizes stars, work in responsive design and need to manage retina and others HD displays, image were too onerous to implement.

I tried CSS shapes, but as I play with different sizes in responsive design (changing root font-size in em modifies the whole page), something accurate in one size, was not in another.

So I used font-face.
On [Icomoon](https://icomoon.io/app/), I picked the star and made a custom font. I put the correct style and that’s it ! I can apply css like I want.

The code looks like this :

HTML :

```
<span class="icon-star"></span>
```

CSS :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    src:url('fonts/icomoon.eot?4n7iw5');
    src:url('fonts/icomoon.eot?#iefix4n7iw5') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/icomoon.woff?4n7iw5') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/icomoon.ttf?4n7iw5') format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/icomoon.svg?4n7iw5#icomoon') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;

    /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.icon-star:before {
    content: "\e600";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this was asked 3 years ago, but I recently ran into the same issue. One way is to use the css [shadow hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32413731/color-for-unicode-emoji/39776303#39776303) Credit goes to Tigran for the original solution:

```
.orange {
  color: transparent;  
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 orange;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do some tricky things will fonts and CSS. You might be able to colour the Samsung font. Check out my other post here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50478585/5078765

Let me know if it works.