# Color for Unicode Emoji

Tags: html, css, unicode, emoji

It's possible to include Emoji characters in modern browsers, but how can one make it a single color and choose that color?

For example, here is some Emoji and some regular (plane 0) Unicode symbols. All should be red, but only the symbols are rendered in red.

[image: Emoji color attempt]

Associated [HTML + CSS](http://jsbin.com/moxusosila/edit?html,css,js,output):

```
<p>
  
</p>
<p>
  ♥★ℹ
</div>

p {
  font-size: 3em;
  color: red
}
```

Comment: none of the below answers work in Firefox and Edge

Answer (score 199, accepted):

Yes, you can color them!

```css
div {
  color: transparent;  
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Nice one! I converted it to a stack snippet. Unfortunately this can only do silhouettes as there's no real encoding for transparency. So e.g. smiley renders same as grimace. Doubt there's much we can do about that.

Comment: Is this a a Mac exclusive :-P, because it doesn’t work on Windows 10 (in any browser).

Comment: Thanks, mahemoff. You're right, some of the more intricate emoticons will look poor, but for most of them it makes little or no difference. And after all, that's the best we can do.

@ŠimeVidas, I'm on Windows 10 myself, Chrome 53.

Comment: In Chrome 53 it works for the outlines, yes. But this does not work in Firefox 49 (emojis stay the same)

Comment: Thx, @nylki. Comes out there was a bug report on the topic - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1128190 , which was for some reason marked as resolved. I added a comment there. Let's wait for Mozilla's response.

Comment: @Tigran My mistake; it works in Chrome and Edge; I was confused by the way the demo in your answer works 

Comment: @ŠimeVidas, on the contrary, your remark gave birth to this bug report, which will hopefully lead to fixing that issue with Firefox soon:  https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1306585 . Nothing in this universe goes in vein. 

Comment: The issue with text-shadow is the emoji cover it up, so building on this answer you could hide the actual emoji by combining the classic large negative margin-left and an equal positive shadow x offset + margin-right (with the unfortunate downside that text selection breaks).

div { text-shadow: 100em 0px 0px red; margin-left: -100em; margin-right: 100em; }

Comment: @PatrickHorn, doesn't setting `color: transparent` work for you?

Comment: `color: transparent` does not work on Firefox version 61.0.1 (on Ubuntu Linux). All normal text becomes transparent but the full color emoji are unaffected.

Comment: @Tigran Can you blur them?

Comment: @mesqueeb, yes, you can, by changing the third value like so: `text-shadow: 0 0 5px red;`.

Comment: This appears black, not red, on my Chrome 78.0.3904.108, Windows 10

Comment: @Betty, shows red for me. Are you still seeing black on Chrome 79?

Comment: @Tigran, yes, I'm on Chrome 79.0.3945.88 now and it's still black.

Comment: @Betty, that's weird. I'm also on Chrome 79.0.3945.88 on Windows 10, and it's red for me.

Comment: It is important to note, that if you are using `::first-letter` and the emoji is the "first letter" - this will not work, even though developer tools will still show correct CSS for the emoji. Most likely will be the same for `::first-line` and maybe some other pseudo elements. This can be worked around, though, obviously by styling the pseudo-elements respectively, but this is not an obvious behavior.

Comment: Can somebody color emojis using SVG?

Comment: @RixTheTyrunt, what do you mean? Color emojis in `<text>` elements inside SVG?

Comment: @RixTheTyrunt `text-shadow` is not applicable to SVG elements. You will have to use [SVG filters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Filter_effects).

Comment: What are those?

Comment: @RixTheTyrunt, please read the MDN guide I linked in my previous comment. That will hopefully give you a good introduction to SVG filters

Comment: So how do you use it? 

Answer (score 56):

Not every emoji works the same. Some are old textual symbols that now have an (optional or default) colorful representation, others were explicitly (only) as emojis. That means, some Unicode codepoints should have two possible representations, `text` and `emoji`. Authors and users should be able to express their preference for one or the other. This is currently done with otherwise invisible [variation selectors](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr51/#Emoji_Variation_Sequences) U+FE0E (`text`, VS-15) and U+FE0F (`emoji`, VS-16), but [higher-level solutions (e.g. for CSS)](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/352) have been proposed.

The text-style emojis are monochromatic and should be displayed in the foreground color, i.e. `currentcolor` in CSS, just like any other glyph. The Unicode Consortium provides an [overview of emojis by style](http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/text-style.html) ([beta version](http://unicode.org/emoji/charts-beta/text-style.html)). You should be able to append `&#xFE0E;` in HTML to select the textual variant with anything in the columns labeled “Default Text Style; *has VSs*” and “Default Emoji Style; *has VSs*”. This doesn’t include the example emojis  and many others, though.

```css
p {
  color: red; font-size: 3em; margin: 0;
  text-transform: text;           /* proposed */
  font-variant-emoji: text;       /* proposed */
  font-variant-color: monochrome; /* proposed */
  font-color: monochrome;         /* proposed */
  font-palette: dark;             /* drafted for CSS Fonts Level 4 */
}
p.hack {
  color: rgba(100%, 0%, 0%, 0);
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 red;
}
p.font {
  font-family: Emojione, Noto, Twemoji, Symbola;
}
@font-face { /* http://emojione.com/developers/ */
  font-family: Emojione;
  src: local("EmojiOne BW"), local("EmojiOne"), local("Emoji One"), 
       /*   https://cdn.rawgit.com/Ranks/emojione/master/assets/fonts/emojione-bw.otf – monochrome only, deprecated, removed
            https://cdn.rawgit.com/Ranks/emojione/master/assets/fonts/emojione-android.ttf – with hack
            https://cdn.rawgit.com/Ranks/emojione/master/assets/fonts/emojione-apple.ttf – with hack */
       url("https://cdn.rawgit.com/Ranks/emojione/master/assets/fonts/emojione-svg.woff2") format("woff2"),
       url("https://cdn.rawgit.com/Ranks/emojione/master/assets/fonts/emojione-svg.woff") format("woff"),
       url("https://cdn.rawgit.com/Ranks/emojione/master/assets/fonts/emojione-svg.otf") format("truetype");
}
@font-face { /* https://www.google.com/get/noto/#noto-emoji-zsye */
  font-family: Noto;
  src: local("Noto Emoji"), local("Noto Color Emoji"), local("Noto"), 
       url("https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlei18n/noto-emoji/master/fonts/NotoEmoji-Regular.ttf");
}
@font-face { /* https://github.com/eosrei/twemoji-color-font/releases */
  font-family: Twemoji;
  src: local("Twemoji");
}
@font-face { /* http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d/ */
  font-family: Symbola;
  src: local("Symbola");
}
```

```html
<p title="♥★ℹ without variation selectors">&#x1F418; &#x1F427; &#x1F43C; &#x2665; &#x2605; &#x2139; &#x1F480; &#x1F44C;</p>
<p title="♥★ℹ with text variation selector 15">&#x1F418;&#xFE0E; &#x1F427;&#xFE0E; &#x1F43C;&#xFE0E; &#x2665;&#xFE0E; &#x2605;&#xFE0E; &#x2139;&#xFE0E; &#x1F480;&#xFE0E; &#x1F44C;&#xFE0E;</p>
<p title="♥★ℹ with emoji variation selector 16">&#x1F418;&#xFE0F; &#x1F427;&#xFE0F; &#x1F43C;&#xFE0F; &#x2665;&#xFE0F; &#x2605;&#xFE0F; &#x2139;&#xFE0F; &#x1F480;&#xFE0F; &#x1F44C;&#xFE0F;</p>
<p title="♥★ℹ with `text-shadow` hack" class="hack">&#x1F418; &#x1F427; &#x1F43C; &#x2665; &#x2605; &#x2139; &#x1F480; &#x1F44C;</p>
<p title="♥★ℹ with custom font" class="font">&#x1F418; &#x1F427; &#x1F43C; &#x2665; &#x2605; &#x2139; &#x1F480; &#x1F44C;</p>
```

I’ve added  U+1F480 Skull and  U+1F44C OK Hand Sign because the background should show through their “eyes” and I’ve used numeric character references just to make the code more obvious and more robust against copy-and-paste errors.

It has been proposed, however, that both variation selectors can be applied to any character, which would have no effect in most cases. Note that some vendors, especially Samsung, are already shipping (default) [emoji glyphs for several other characters](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KQDH9uArJr-8m4UvAEd02ixaX_-wauSwjy9qYCwIOvE/edit) (`goo.gl/a4yK6p` or `goo.gl/DqtHcc`).

Comment: Text variation selector is definitely the best answer for the original question! 

Comment: The link to the variation selector doc on unicode.org seems to be down, although http://unicode.org/faq/vs.html is now the official FAQ page.

Comment: Can somebody please do this in SVG?

Answer (score 34):

I wanted to do this myself so I've recently come up with a solution using newer CSS effects that works on Firefox and Edge as well.

Using filter, you first normalize the color by using sepia(1), you then saturate the heck out of it to get a pure red. If you want to get rid of black lines, suck the contrast out of the emoji before applying other filters using contrast(0). After that you just spin the colour wheel from red to whatever color you'd like using hue-rotate(). Note that because I used decimal values instead of %'s, a value of 100 means 10000%.

Hue offsets are defined as beginning at red. We are lucky that sepia is mostly red so the wheel starts off perfectly at 0-degrees. You can calculate what offset you want using a RGB to HSL converter. I found a nice one written in Javascript here: https://web.archive.org/web/20180808220922/http://axonflux.com/handy-rgb-to-hsl-and-rgb-to-hsv-color-model-c

You must multiply the hue value by 360 to get the desired result from that function. An example would be `rgbToHsl(0,100,100)[0]*360`. Which would return 180. Since there is no red, this would be the expected result, you would be spinning 180 degrees away from red.

As Litherium an Crissov pointed out, there are text emojis as well. These work better with transformations and often look better. You can't apply the method I have described above however, until you first apply `invert(.5)` on the text emojis, this is because the functions need some sort of shade to operate on. So simply adding `invert(.5)` to the beginning of each formula, allows for them to operate on both code points on all browsers.

```css
.a { /* Normalize colour to a primary red */
    filter: sepia(1) saturate(100);
}
.b { /* Less saturation so more features, shifted colour 90-degrees */
    filter: sepia(1) saturate(5)  hue-rotate(90deg);
}
.c { /* Remove black outlines if desired by removing contrast */
    filter: contrast(0) sepia(1) saturate(100) hue-rotate(180deg);
}
.d { /* Other shades possible by lowering brightness */
    filter: contrast(0) sepia(1) saturate(100) brightness(.05) hue-rotate(180deg);
}
.e { /* Weird possibilities with no colour normalization */
    filter: contrast(100) hue-rotate(180deg);
}
.ma { /* Invert to provide a gray shade to apply sepia*/
    filter: invert(.5) sepia(1) saturate(100);
}
div {
    font-size: 25px;
}
.emo > div::after {
    content: "⛄";
}
.mono > div::after {
    content: "\1F30D\FE0E\26C4\FE0E\1F60D\FE0E\1F431\FE0E";
}
```

```html
<div class="emo">
    <div>-:</div>
    <div class="a">a:</div>
    <div class="b">b:</div>
    <div class="c">c:</div>
    <div class="d">d:</div>
    <div class="e">e:</div>
</div>
<span>Change the code point to text mode:</span>
<div class="mono">
    <div class="a">a:</div>
    <div class="ma">ma:</div>
</div>
```

Update: 
There are newer packages available on npm now that can calculate hues etc. You don't need to use that snippet on the website I had previously linked. Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56082323/5078765

Comment: @Mas Glad I could help. Because this technique requires css filter effects, please check to make sure the browsers that you want to be supported are supported: https://caniuse.com/#search=filter
That being said, specifying the text variant by appending the unicode FE0E and then applying a text-shadow as Crissov mentions, is also effective. If you only want to support modern browsers however, the method using filters allows you to use the emoji format, which may be useful if you are applying it to dynamic text.

Comment: It looks like Edge now supports coloring them via `text-shadow` now as well... So I guess you can disregard all this voodoo that I did here if you're only supporting the the latest browsers.

Answer (score 27):

You can fill them with a solid color:

[image: solid]

```css
p {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 blue;
}
```

```html
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
```

Or you can outline them:

[image: outline]

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px blue;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

p::before {
  content: attr(title);
  position: absolute;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 #fff;
}
```

```html
<p title=""></p>
<p title=""></p>
<p title=""></p>
```

Comment: I prefer to use another attribute such as `name` for the outline so that when users have the emoji it doesn't show in a tooltip. Great answer!

Answer (score 19):

If you want to keep the details within the emoji you can use [`filter: url(svg)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#SVG_filter) where `url()` will take an [svg filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/filter)

```css
svg {
  display: none;
}

div {
  -webkit-filter: url(#red);
  filter: url(#red);
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <filter id="red">
    <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="
      1 0 0 0 0
      0 0 0 0 0
      0 0 0 0 0
      0 0 0 1 0" />
  </filter>
</svg>

<div></div>
```

While the use of `feColorMatrix` may seem daunting at first, it is actually straight forward to define your own colors. Take the following example which represents the color red:

```
1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0
```

If you grab the **bold** values from above, we can see how they relate to the RGBA color mode:

```
1 - red   (r)
0 - green (g)
0 - blue  (b)
1 - alpha (a)
```

Here each color relates to a value from 0 to 255 divided by 255. Thus, if you had the color green, which has a RGBA of:

```
 R   G   B  A
(0, 255, 0, 1)
```

Then your values would be:

```
0/255   -> 0 (r)
255/255 -> 1 (g)
0/255   -> 0 (b)
1       -> 1 (a) - don't divide
```

And so, using these values in our matrix we get:

```
0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0
```

You can now add this as an additional filter (or remove the old one) and give it an `id` so that it can be referenced within css `filter: url(#filterID)`

See implemented version below:

```css
svg {
  display: none;
}

.red {
  -webkit-filter: url(#red);
  filter: url(#red);
}

.green {
  -webkit-filter: url(#green);
  filter: url(#green);
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <filter id="red">
    <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="
      1 0 0 0 0
      0 0 0 0 0
      0 0 0 0 0
      0 0 0 1 0" />
  </filter>
  
  <!--         \/ --- change id to be referenced within css -->
  <filter id="green">
    <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="
      0 0 0 0 0
      0 1 0 0 0
      0 0 0 0 0
      0 0 0 1 0" />
  </filter>
</svg>

<div class="red"></div>
<div class="green"></div>
```

#### `<feColorMatrix />` color  matrix generator:

For convenience, I've made a `feColorMatrix` generator, which allows you to pick or enter a color as well as an opacity and generate a feColorMatrix from that color:

```js
const colorPicker = document.getElementById("color-picker");
const alphaPicker = document.getElementById("alpha-picker");
const codeOutput = document.getElementById("code-output");
const alphaValue = document.getElementById("alpha-value");
const pickedFilter = document.getElementById("picked-filter");
let r=0, g=0, b=0, a=1;

const generateFeColorMatrix = () => `<feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="
  ${r} 0 0 0 0
  0 ${g} 0 0 0
  0 0 0 ${b} 0
  0 0 0 ${a} 0" 
/>
`;

const update = () => {
  const feColorMatrixStr = generateFeColorMatrix();
  codeOutput.textContent = feColorMatrixStr;
  pickedFilter.innerHTML = feColorMatrixStr;
}

colorPicker.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
  const hexparts = e.target.value.match(/(\w{1,2})/g);
  ([r,g,b] = hexparts.map(hex => (parseInt(hex, 16) / 255).toFixed(2))); 
  update();
});

alphaPicker.addEventListener("input", e => {
  a = e.target.value;
  alphaValue.textContent = a;
  update();
});
alphaValue.textContent = a;
```

```css
svg {
  display: none;
}

#color-picker {
  float: right;
}

#code-output {
  background-color: #f6f6f6; 
}

#emojis {
  -webkit-filter: url(#picked-filter);
  filter: url(#picked-filter);
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<input type="color" id="color-picker" />
<input type="range" id="alpha-picker" value="1" min="0" max="1" step="0.01"/><span id="alpha-value">1</span>
<pre id="code-output">
</pre>
<svg>
  <filter id="picked-filter"></filter>
</svg>
<p id="emojis"></p>
```

**Please note** Currently, this solution has very limited browser support. To see a full list of browsers supported by this feature please see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#Browser_compatibility).

Answer (score 9):

Some, but not all, code points can be drawn in either text form (non-picture-based glyph) or emoji form (picture-based glyph). Unicode describes that these two forms can be selected by using one of two variation selectors: either U+FE0E (VARIATION SELECTOR-15) or U+FE0F (VARIATION SELECTOR-16). When drawn in non-picture-based form, the `color` CSS property should apply.

Example:

U+2603 (SNOWMAN) is drawn this way: ☃

The sequence of code points U+2603 U+FE0E is drawn this way: ☃︎

The sequence of code points U+2603 U+FE0F is drawn this way: ☃️

More information, along with a full list of the code points which participate in these variation sequences, can be found at http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/emoji-variants.html

(Note that different operating systems may choose a different default when the bare code point is used. For example, try viewing this post in macOS and iOS - the bare code point above looks different!)

Comment: How do you use a sequence of code points? &#x2603; shows the plain one. How to I show the color one?

Comment: Just put the two characters next to each other.

Answer (score 3):

The SVG matrix solution by Nick Parsons can be also converted to an in-line solution using the `data:` scheme:

```css
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><filter id='f'><feColorMatrix color-interpolation-filters='sRGB' type='matrix' values='0 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 1 0'/></filter></svg>#f");
```

`color-interpolation-filters='sRGB'` is there since some browsers use a different default color space.

I also recommend adding a grayscale filter, since otherwise some emojis will lose contrast if pure colors are used:

```css
filter: grayscale(100%) url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><filter id='f'><feColorMatrix color-interpolation-filters='sRGB' type='matrix' values='0 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 1 0'/></filter></svg>#f");
```

The grayscale filter may also be represented by a matrix and incorporated into the SVG data. Here is one that should match human perception better than what CSS offers:

```css
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><filter id='f'><feColorMatrix color-interpolation-filters='linearRGB' type='matrix' values='0.2126 0.7152 0.0722 0 0  0.2126 0.7152 0.0722 0 0  0.2126 0.7152 0.0722 0 0  0 0 0 1 0'/><feColorMatrix color-interpolation-filters='sRGB' type='matrix' values='0 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 1 0'/></filter></svg>#f");
```

Lastly, here is some PHP code that generates the matrix from a given color (entered as a CSS hex-based color code):

```php
function matrixcolor($hex)
{
  list($r, $g, $b) = array_map(function($c) {return $c / 255 / 3;}, sscanf($hex, "#%02x%02x%02x"));
  return "$r $r $r 0 0  $g $g $g 0 0  $b $b $b 0 0";
}

function colormatrix($col)
{
  return "url(\"data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><filter id='f'><feColorMatrix color-interpolation-filters='linearRGB' type='matrix' values='0.2126 0.7152 0.0722 0 0  0.2126 0.7152 0.0722 0 0  0.2126 0.7152 0.0722 0 0  0 0 0 1 0'/><feColorMatrix color-interpolation-filters='sRGB' type='matrix' values='".matrixcolor($col)."  0 0 0 1 0'/></filter></svg>#f\")";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As Emoji is quite new, styling it is not yet supported natively.

The workaround is to use an Emoji font such as [Twitter's Twemoji](https://github.com/twitter/twemoji). Then it can be styled much the same way Font Awesome or native Unicode can be styled.

Answer (score -3):

IF YOU NEED TO USE CSS AFTER,BEFORE PSEUDO ELEMENT YOU CAN PROCED LIKE THIS

```
<span class="react-thumb-fly" title="Aimé">
   <button class="react-toggle-icon-thumb"></button>
</span>
```

THEN WRITE THIS FOR CSS

```
.react-toggle-icon-thumb {
  width: 20pt;
  height: 20pt;
  font-size: 30pt;
  position: relative;
  color: gray;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  top: -0px;
}
.react-toggle-icon-thumb:before, .react-toggle-icon-thumb:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
  content: "";
  font-family: fontawesome;
  color: transparent;  
 text-shadow: 0 0 0 #3498db;
}

.react-toggle-icon-thumb:hover:before {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  animation: thumbs-up 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes thumbs-up {
 25% {
  transform: rotate(20deg);
 }
 50%, 100% {
   transform: rotate(5deg);
 }
}
```