# Unicode character in link is not highlighted on hover

Tags: html, css, unicode, hyperlink, hover

Why (what's the intent behind) unicode character doesn't highlight when the other text hightlights?

```css
a:hover
{
  color: #ffd800;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Some text that is hightlighted but why this symbol  doesn't highlight!??</a>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Color for Unicode Emoji](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32413731/color-for-unicode-emoji)

Comment: @IiroP ty for the link. But why these unicode symbols are treated differently from common symbols (ascii letters, digits, punctuation marksetc.), any sane reason?

Comment: I don't get the issue here. The symbol does change the color when I hover over it.

Comment: @KiranDash what browser you are using? I tested on chrome (Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36). Might be chrome only issue... On IE (Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko) highlight works though.

Comment: Well I too use chrome. :)

Comment: Just checked it on firefox. And yes it does not highlight there.

Comment: @KiranDash Thanks!:-) At least chrome and firefox go along :D

Answer (score 1):

That symbol is called emoji (extended unicode). It's colorful right now when displayed on Chrome, Opera, Safari..., so you CANNOT change its color. If you look at that symbol carefully, you can see its color is gray with black border (on Windows, it's different on MacOS,...). If you check it on IE/Edge, may be you can see the change (because IE/Edge don't support colorful emoji right now).

Comment: Thank you for this clarification. The visual appearance characteristic can be changed tough :) with css: `.un:hover /*for unicode highlight*/
{
    color:transparent;
    text-shadow: 0 0 0 #ffd800;
}` and html `<a href="#" class="un">Some text that is hightlighted completely .</a>`

Comment: You can add the effect for them, for example: filter. It will make the change, but not color. The color property won't changed!