# HTML Symbol doesn`t change the color ... always RED

Tags: html

How to change the color of the phone? It doesn't want to change! I want to change the color, but nothing happens.

```html
<span style="color: #808080;">☎</span>
```

Comment: This is an emoji, actually. I dont think you can change its color.

Comment: @nicael, it was a bad question to begin with, but by removing the example URL you have removed a critical amount of relevant information - the issue is _not_ actually with this snippet of HTML code that's left now.

Comment: @Cbroe link is, essentially, useless info, because no matter where the color of the emoji stays the same and cant be changed via css.

Comment: @carmen, in general and for the next time, please go read [ask] and [mcve]. What the actual issue is here however only becomes apparent after a look at the DOM using browser dev tools - WP has replaced your ☎ character inside the span element with `<img draggable="false" class="emoji" alt="☎" src="https://s.w.org/images/core/emoji/2.4/svg/260e.svg">` - and [that SVG](https://s.w.org/images/core/emoji/2.4/svg/260e.svg) just happens to be a red-ish telefon icon. Solution to that issue: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/185577/disable-emojicons-introduced-with-wp-4-2

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32413731/color-for-unicode-emoji

Answer (score 0):

The code for a Black Telephone symbol is &#9742 ;
There is also another alternative code for the above i.e. &#x260E ;

The code for a White Telephone symbol is
 &#9743 ;
There is also another alternative code for the above i.e  &#x260F ;
For example,

1. ☎
2. ☏

Answer (score 0):

As far as the content between the span, it can change the colors or background via CSS or html style.  Youre on the right track.  But it can easily be changed to red and back to its default color as you desire.  Here is my [Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/NitroXAce/hmuh64La/5/) on it.

It has both a default color and a condition to change it.  I assume its HTML code friendly.  (Added the unicode for Pi to be sure, and it also behaves like your emoji).  So as long as the html unicode is present, its likely treated as a font character that can be edit via colors.  Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

&#9742 try this. this might help you.

Answer (score -1):

This is an emoji. I don't think you can change it's color. Try using fontawesome or bootstrap icons. Their colors can be changed easily.