# MS Edge not applying css style "color" on unicode symbols

Tags: css, microsoft-edge

I have a following code:

```html
<span style="color: blue;" title="square">◼</span>
```

The color is properly applied in Chrome, FF, Opera, IE11, but Edge is ignoring it and displaying as black.

Could you give me an advice or this is a bad approach?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Color for Unicode Emoji](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32413731/color-for-unicode-emoji)

Comment: No, I have tried this before asking. It seems "color" style is not affecting them at all.

Comment: I referred to that mainly for the explanation of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/11635143/) you can specify font-family to your span to get it work:

```
<span style="color: blue; font-family: 'Segoe UI Symbol'" title="square">◼</span>
```