# Grey out emoji characters (HTML / CSS)

Tags: html, css, colors, emoji

My current issue is that I am trying to grey out a button with emojis in it.

Nevertheless it seems that, due the nature of emojis, it is not possible to change the color using HTML / CSS properties.

I.e.:

```html
<button disabled> _myText </button>

<p style="color:grey">
  _myText2
</p>
```

Comment: Checked in Chrome / firefox

Comment: Tried with CSS filters. But they are only applicable to real images.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Color for Unicode Emoji](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32413731/color-for-unicode-emoji)

Comment: Thank you Amit for your suggestion. The linked issue is interesting but it is not the same problem and have different solutions than the ones listed here:

Think on a football  and baseball emojis:
 - Greying it out should keep the internal shapes with just grey colors (actual grey out meaning); balls are distinguishable
 - With your solution, we just get a one color shape with no internal shapes; football and basketballs  become indistinct black circles

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you're looking to just change the Emoji colour to grey, you can do so using [`filter: grayscale`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#Filter_functions):

```html
<button style="filter: grayscale(100%);" disabled>_myText</button>

<p style="color: grey; filter: grayscale(100%);">_myText2</p>
```

If you wish to colour your Emojis in other colours see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55221809/5648954)

Comment: Any text editor that mangles emoji *is a bad tool that should not be used*. If it mangles emoji, it’s very likely to be mangling other things too, since it clearly has fundamental encoding problems. I therefore strongly disagree with your suggestion, which makes more work for everyone for no manifestly good reason. (And everything should be using UTF-8 already.)

Answer (score 8):

You can use text shadow

```html
 <button disabled> _myText </button>

    <p style="color:transparent; text-shadow: 0 0 0 grey;">
      _myText2
    </p>
```

**Update:** This just shows the shadow of character, using `filter:` is better idea in most cases

Comment: this displays a gray silhouette of the emoji