# I'm trying to make a game prototype to print with CSS and Javascript, but the icons are losing color when the print tab is open

Tags: javascript, css, printing

i'm using icons like ,  and  but they always lose the color when i try to print, i used:

```
 @media print  {
    .game-card-reactions {
      -webkit-break-inside: avoid;
      break-inside: avoid;
      -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact!important; 
    }
}
```

worked for the colors on the cards, but didn't work on the icons...
[Actual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2lCo.png) [Desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Px4Li.png)

The colors are important because of the color code on the side of the cards

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me in most situations regarding print color

```
@media print {
  *{
    color-adjust: exact;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
    print-color-adjust: exact;
  }
}
```

Comment: Tryed that, the icons are utf-8 and skill without their original color

Comment: Can you try the `text-shadow` solution here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32413731/color-for-unicode-emoji/39776303#39776303

Comment: The icons must have diferent colors