# Css for a span element works on desktop but not mobile. Element is added using jquery .append()

Tags: html, jquery, css

Pretty much as the question states.

I can only place html/scripts in limited places (don't have access to the direct html or source files) so am adding in a short script to add ratings.

It's meant to display 3 chillis and depending on the rating they will all be red or some red some white. It works perfectly fine on desktop versions but for mobile it's showing all icons as red and is not picking up the chilli-white css. Anyone have any ideas why?

```js
var spicyRating3 = "<span class='chilli-red'>&#127798; &#127798; &#127798;</span>";
var spicyRating2 = "<span class='chilli-red'>&#127798; &#127798;</span><span class='chilli-white'>&#127798;</span>";
var spicyRating1 = "<span class='chilli-red'>&#127798;</span><span class='chilli-white'>&#127798; &#127798;</span>";
$(".rating-3").append(spicyRating3);
$(".rating-2").append(spicyRating2);
$(".rating-1").append(spicyRating1);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.agenda .chilli-red {
  color: #ff0000;
}

.agenda .chilli-white {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<p class="rating-3"></p>
<p class="rating-2"></p>
<p class="rating-1"></p>
```

Desktop (how it should look)
[image: 1 chilli rating correct]

Mobile (should only show one chilli but all are red/not working)
[image: 3 chilli rating incorrect]

Comment: I'm on desktop Chrome and they're all red.

Comment: The chilli emoji has an embedded colour

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Color for Unicode Emoji](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32413731/color-for-unicode-emoji)

Comment: So this sounds like a difference in the fonts.

Comment: I'm not too worried about desktop, it's working as it needs to. The embedded colour seems like that might be it, @Phil do you know how I can override the embedded colour?

Comment: Nevermind I read that link properly and that was perfect - thank you! Sorry I initially said the suggestion was wrong, if you could do it again I can mark as correct

Answer (score 0):

Use transparent colour with a white text-shadow to render white chillies.

```js
var spicyRating3 = "<span class='chilli-red'>&#127798; &#127798; &#127798;</span>";
var spicyRating2 = "<span class='chilli-red'>&#127798; &#127798;</span><span class='chilli-white'>&#127798;</span>";
var spicyRating1 = "<span class='chilli-red'>&#127798;</span><span class='chilli-white'>&#127798; &#127798;</span>";
document.querySelector(".rating-3").innerHTML = spicyRating3;
document.querySelector(".rating-2").innerHTML = spicyRating2;
document.querySelector(".rating-1").innerHTML = spicyRating1;
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.chilli-white {
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 #fff;
}
```

```html
<p class="rating-3"></p>
<p class="rating-2"></p>
<p class="rating-1"></p>
```

Or use SVG images instead of emoji

```js
var spicyRating3 = '<img src="https://donald.au/bugs/so-77233608/chilli-red.svg"><img src="https://donald.au/bugs/so-77233608/chilli-red.svg"><img src="https://donald.au/bugs/so-77233608/chilli-red.svg">';
var spicyRating2 = '<img src="https://donald.au/bugs/so-77233608/chilli-red.svg"><img src="https://donald.au/bugs/so-77233608/chilli-red.svg"><img src="https://donald.au/bugs/so-77233608/chilli-white.svg">';
var spicyRating1 = '<img src="https://donald.au/bugs/so-77233608/chilli-red.svg"><img src="https://donald.au/bugs/so-77233608/chilli-white.svg"><img src="https://donald.au/bugs/so-77233608/chilli-white.svg">';

document.querySelector(".rating-3").innerHTML = spicyRating3;
document.querySelector(".rating-2").innerHTML = spicyRating2;
document.querySelector(".rating-1").innerHTML = spicyRating1;
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
p.rating-1 img, p.rating-2 img, p.rating-3 img {
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<p class="rating-3"></p>
<p class="rating-2"></p>
<p class="rating-1"></p>
```

Answer (score -2):

Updated css to the below and it works as required now - explanation here [Color for Unicode Emoji](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32413731/color-for-unicode-emoji) thanks Phil for the link

```css
.agenda .chilli-red {
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 #ff0000;
}
.agenda .chilli-white {
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 #fff;
}
```